# CakePHP 1.3 query question

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to convert working query to CakePHP find. So I fail, try to use Containable behavior and so on, but no luck. Please help me convert this SQL query to CakePHP find:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(da.dealer_id))
    FROM dealer_access_list da, dealers d
    WHERE   da.dealer_id NOT IN (SELECT dealer_id FROM fixture_inventory)
    AND d.disabled = 0
    AND d.do_not_include IS NOT TRUE
    AND da.dealer_id = d.dealer_id
```

Thank you!

I have problems with joining more that two tables and using SQL special functions. I want to use CakePHP ORM and not plain SQL if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake used to have the -! syntax for running SQL inside the find, which would have come in handy with your nested query. But with that deprecated, as far as I know, you might have to break it into 2 pieces.

I'm going to put my answer here using two queries, till someone can put up an alternative with the nested query

```
$dealers  = //get the dealer IDs in the table in the normal way. make sure it's an array of only the IDs

$opts = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'COUNT(DISTINCT(da.dealer_id)) AS count_dealer_id'
   ),
  'conditions' => array(
    'NOT' => array('da.dealer_id' => $dealers),
    'd.disabled' => 0,
    'd.do_not_include IS NOT TRUE',
  )
)
$results = $this->find('all', $opts); //assuming you're in the correct model
```

As long as you have the associations setup properly in the models, cake will figure out the correct joins and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. I hope this is the best way :)

Comment: So.. There is small problem.. dealers table have ~20 000 records and when I try to get all of them, then 128Mb of script allocation is not enaught. Is there alternative solution?

Comment: I added a little changes, now working query is this, but can't get working with CakePHP ORM:    `$query = 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Dealer.id))
      FROM _dealers Dealer, _dealers_users DealersUsers, _user_relations UserRelation
      WHERE DealersUsers.user_id = UserRelation.user_id
      AND Dealer.id = DealersUsers.dealer_id
      AND Dealer.do_not_include_in_stats IS NOT TRUE
      AND Dealer.disabled = 0
      AND UserRelation.parent_id = '.$user['id'];
    
    $active_dealers = $this->User->query($query, false);`

Comment: You shouldn't be retrieving all dealer records. You should first set `recursive` to `-1` and retrieve only the IDs. As for your query, why can't you get it to work?

Comment: MMm.. yes - it as my fault. Will try to set recursive to -1 and then get all dealer_id. Will try later it, then post what I got. Thanks!

Comment: Ex.. I had to make changes in table structure and now it seen different, so find options will now see different, really, I don't know how to make it now, but I got the idea! Thanks you all for advice and help!